# LPTHW, EX19 extra credit 3

Tags: python

I'm doing Zed Shaw's LPTHW book but I am stuck at this extra credit 3 [question](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex19.html) and found no question here related so I decided to make an account.

**Extra credit assignment:** 
Write at least one more function of your own design, and run it 10 different ways.

Code:

```
def cheese_and_crackers(cheese_count, boxes_of_crackers):
    print "You have %d cheeses!" % cheese_count
    print "You have %d boxes of crackers!" % boxes_of_crackers
    print "Man that's enough for a party!"
    print "Get a blanket.\n"


print "We can just give the function numbers directly:"
cheese_and_crackers(20, 30)


print "OR, we can use variables from our script:"
amount_of_cheese = 10
amount_of_crackers = 50

cheese_and_crackers(amount_of_cheese, amount_of_crackers)


print "We can even do math inside too:"
cheese_and_crackers(10 + 20, 5 + 6)


print "And we can combine the two, variables and math:"
cheese_and_crackers(amount_of_cheese + 100, amount_of_crackers + 1000)
```

So, what are the other ways to run a function inside your script? Could you please help me out in a beginner detailed manner that includes actual code so I can try and understand it?

Comment: You could always assign the function to a variable and then invoke it that way. E.g. "foo = cheese_and_crackers; foo(10,20)` Admittedly kind of trivial.

Comment: What about running it in a loop? Or passing the function to another function which will call it?

Comment: @PeterRowell Well, I'm a beginner and I am not looking at this as trivial or not. I just want to find out more ways of running functions. Thanks for contributing with your reply, I didn't knew I can asign functions to variables. If you know other ways regardless of their "programming aesthetics" please write them down here. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasK I haven't learned loops yet and I can't "visualize" in code that example. If it's possible, could you please write the code in Python for both examples? If you have others, I'm more than happy but please try to provide the actual code. Thanks a lot Thomas for taking the time to write a reply.

Comment: OK, I've looked up LPTHW now. How about calling a function to make one of the arguments? E.g. `int(raw_input("how much cheese? "))`. In fact, that's using two functions, but you get the idea.

Comment: @Drageek: I wasn't meaning to dis you. That comment was more for other old Pythonistas than aimed at you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm consolidating the comments into an answer here.

```
print 'We can assign the function to a variable and simply call it by its new name'
foo = cheese_and_crackers
foo(20,30)

print 'We can call the function in a loop, calling it 10 times'
for i in range(10):
    cheese_and_crackers(20,30)

print 'We can pass a function as arguments.'
print 'We can now ask the user for the number of cheese and crackers'
cheese_and_crackers(int(raw_input('how many cheese?')), int(raw_input('how many crackers?')))
```

Comment: "I'm consolidating the comments into an answer here." That makes it [**community wiki**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Answer (score 1):

I could add a few more ways:

```
#the sum function
def displaySum(a,b):
  sum = a + b
  print "The sum is: %d" % sum

print "#1:"
displaySum(5,10)                #1


print "#2:"
x=3
k=7                             #2
displaySum(x,k)

print "#3:"
displaySum(5+5, 10+10)          #3

print "#4:"
displaySum(x+5,k+10)            #4

print "#5:"
var1 = int(raw_input("p1: "))   #5
var2 = int(raw_input("p2: "))
displaySum(var1,var2)


def passValue():                #6
  x1 = 100 
  x2 = 200
  displaySum(x1,x2)

print "#6:" 
passValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv

a, u = argv

def get_length(arg):
    return len(arg)

# 1
print get_length(u)
# 2
print get_length(u+'leaf')
# 3
print get_length(u+'5'*4)
# 4
print get_length('length\n')
# 5
print get_length('length'+'python')
# 6
print get_length('length'*6)
# 7
temp = 'length'
print get_length(temp)
# 8
print get_length(temp+'python')
# 9
print get_length(temp*6)
# 10
print get_length(open(raw_input('filenanme: ')).read())
# 11
print get_length(raw_input('a string:'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use command line arguments:

```
from sys import argv
script, arg1, arg2 = argv

cheese_and_crackers(int(arg1), int(arg2))
```

Or read both inputs from a file:

```
txt = open('filename.txt')
arg1 = int(txt.readline())
arg2 = int(txt.readline())
cheese_and_crackers(arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner and I'm doing ex19 too. Maybe you just think too much. I think the purpose of Zed is just tell us:"try to use something I told you before ex19", so, I just combine something I learned before ex19 to make 10 different ways. I can not give any advices, just my own work, I'll be happy if you can get some more idea from it.

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
def bbc(a, b, c, d):
    e = "\nI want to buy {} \nAnd I want to buy {} either \nI even want to get {} \nAll right I'll give you {} books"
    print(e.format(a, b, c, d))

book1, book2, book3, book4, book5 = argv 

a1 = "python book"
b1 = "C books"
c1 = "java books"
d1 = 2

#method1 string
bbc("python books", "C books", "java books", "2")

#method2 variables
bbc(a1, b1, c1, d1)

#method3 number with math
bbc(a1, b1, c1, d1*3)

#method4 string with math
bbc(
"python books" + " either python2.0 or 3.0 is ok", 
"C books" + " or C++ book is ok", 
"java books" + " I mean javascript", 
"2 + 2")

#method5 variables with math
a2 = " either python2.0 or 3.0 is ok"
b2 = " or C++ book is ok"
c2 = " I mean javascript"
bbc(a1 + a2, b1 + b2, c1 + c2, d1 + d1)

#method6 "input" to arguments
d2 = input("num")
bbc(a1, b1, c1, d2)

#method7 "argv" to arguments
bbc(book2, book3, book4, book5)

#method8 "exists" to arguments
txt1 = "Guitar.txt"
txt2 = "Time Travel.txt"
txt3 = "A song for love.txt"
txt4 = "Wonderful Tonight.txt"
bbc(exists(txt1), exists(txt2), exists(txt3), exists(txt4))

#method9 "len" to arguments
I1 = input("name1\t")
I2 = input("name2\t")
I3 = input("name3\t")
I4 = input("name4\t")

W1 = open(I1, "w").write("close")
W2 = open(I2, "w").write("lose")
W3 = open(I3, "w").write("ose")
W4 = open(I4, "w").write("se")

L1 = open(I1).read()
L2 = open(I2).read()
L3 = open(I3).read()
L4 = open(I4).read()
bbc(len(L1), len(L2), len(L3), len(L4))

#method10 "int" to arguments
int1 = int(input("integer 20\t"))
int2 = int(input("binary 10100\t"), 2)
int3 = int(input("octal 24\t"), 8)
int4 = int(float(input("float 20.9\t")))
bbc(int1, int2, int3, int4)
```

Answer (score -1):

import random

```
first = random.randrange(1, 10)  
second = random.randrange(1,10)  
cheese_and_crackers(first, second)
```